# Python datetime with months and year only

Tags: python, time-series

I'm trying to convert my dataset variable `'DATE'` into a `%Y.%m` format but having the datatype as `'datetime'`.

Now, I've try to do this:

```
testdata['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(testdata['DATE'], format='%Y-%m')
```

But it returns me a format of `'%Y-%m-%d'`. Can someone explain to me why?

(The reason why I'm trying to do this is because I'm dealing with a time series algorithm for machine learning. And I THINK that I would need my date to be a datetime, but I only have month plus year data.

Comment: `to_datetime` converts a string to a datetime object.  A datetime object does not have a format.  It's a simple integer that represents a point in time.  If you want it printed or displayed with a specific format, then you need to do that formatting when you display it.

Comment: I'm trying to have my variable 'DATE' with this datetime dtype, but by doing that my data variable gets like '2022-05-01', and i wanted it to be '2022-05' only with a dtype of: DATE          datetime64[ns]

Comment: You are missing the point.  The datetime value is stored as the number of seconds since some starting point.  It doesn't HAVE year/month/day/hour/minute/second, but it represents a single second in time.  If you convert '2022-05' with '%Y-%m", you create a datetime object that represents 00:00:00 on 2022/05/01.  It HAS no inherent format.  When you need to present that item to a user, **YOU** decide what format to use, by converting to a string.  That's YOUR job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the format returned is '%Y-%m-%d' is because pandas, by default, fills in the missing day and time values with the minimum possible values, which are '01' for the day and '00:00:00' for the time.

However, if you don't need the day and time information in your analysis, you can simply extract the year and month from the datetime object and create a new column with the desired format using the strftime method:

```
testdata['YEAR_MONTH'] = testdata['DATE'].dt.strftime('%Y.%m')
```

This will create a new column called 'YEAR_MONTH' with the format '%Y.%m', containing only the year and month information.

Comment: Yes, but when i do that my 'DATE' dtype becames a 'Object', and i would like to keep this as 'datetime' you know?

Comment: @Marteusa you're misunderstanding what a datetime is.  It ALWAYS contains the full date and time, whether you specify them or not. If you want something less specific you need to choose a different type.

Comment: @Marteusa you can use the pd.PeriodIndex method to create a new column with the desired format while keeping the datetime data type

Comment: @Mark Ransom I see, i wanted to do this because in a time series machine learning algorithm we need our index to be a datetime, but since my data contains only years and months i was not understanding how I could keep the datetime format as long as the month and year only without having a 'day' like 01. So I can just keep the 'day' and continue my analyse for month having the 'wrong' format?

Comment: If you're doing the analysis with datetime objects, then they are going to represent a single point in time, not a whole month.  You can do whatever analysis you need using those values.  If you're doing date arithmetic, then you need to worry about the fact that months are not all the same length, and in that case, maybe another representation is better.

Comment: @Tim Roberts it does make sense, thank you!

Comment: Also, it wouldn't cause any problem in my analysis if i just had the '2018-10-01' representing the whole month, wouldn't it?

Comment: You are the only one who knows that.  We don't know what analysis you're preparing to do.  For most forward projections, it's probably fine.

Comment: @Time Roberts Oh, i'm trying to do an exercise where i need to predict the monthly sales for a 'company', so that's why i've so many doubts about this, i'm still kinda new to this 'time series' problems. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly as written above, but Pandas has also `Period` class where you don't have to supply day if you dont have it. Maybe it will help you.

```py
pandas_period = pd.Period('2023-05', 'M')
print("value: {}, type: {}".format(pandas_period, type(pandas_period)))
```

```
value: 2023-05, type: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period'>
```

Comment: I also though about that, i was only not fully conviced i could do the time series analysis with the period method. Thank you! :)